# in ASP.NET,Jquery Toggle is not working on fieldset-legend

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have `fieldset` > legend in `Update Panel` . I m using jquery toggle on legend, on 1st page load,it is working fine.

Inside update panel , I have button, on click of it partial postback happend & one new filedset>legend, will open.

Now jquery toggle is not working, on both fieldset-legend.

**Code:**

```
   $('fieldset').delegate('legend.test', 'click', function (ev) { ev.preventDefault();  
   $(this).next("div.showhidefsl").slideToggle("fast"); 
   $(this).parent("fieldset").toggleClass("fieldsetborderToggle");
   $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: $('fieldset').delegate('legend.test', 'click', function (ev) {
        
        ev.preventDefault();                        
        $(this).next("div.showhidefsl").slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).parent("fieldset").toggleClass("fieldsetborderToggle");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        
    });

Answer (score 0):

if this is not working after asynch postback use:

```
  function pageLoad(){
    $('fieldset').delegate('legend.test', 'click', function (ev) { 
      ev.preventDefault(); 
      $(this).next("div.showhidefsl").slideToggle("fast"); 
      $(this).parent("fieldset").toggleClass("fieldsetborderToggle"); 
      $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
    }
```

another option is use asynchronous events:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function() {
$('fieldset').delegate('legend.test', 'click', function (ev) { 
          ev.preventDefault(); 
          $(this).next("div.showhidefsl").slideToggle("fast"); 
          $(this).parent("fieldset").toggleClass("fieldsetborderToggle"); 
          $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
    });
```

instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code
});
```

Comment: the function is under $(document).ready(function(){... aleardy

Comment: '$(document).ready(function(){' is not called when you do asynchronous postback

Answer (score 0):

Register your delegate with live() or on() event.

```
$('fieldset').live('legend.test', 'click', function (ev) { 
  ev.preventDefault(); 
  $(this).next("div.showhidefsl").slideToggle("fast"); 
  $(this).parent("fieldset").toggleClass("fieldsetborderToggle"); 
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
}
```